# How can I check if 'middleman build' passed with travis ci?

Tags: travis-ci, middleman

i'm trying to use travis ci for the first time and stumbled across the issue. My project uses [middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) and [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) that executes during build, hence I want to test for 'middleman build' inside travis ci to see if it is passing, but am not able to figure it out.

Here is repo I'm trying to test: https://github.com/IljaDaderko/middleman-starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a Travis build will fail if any of its build commands return a non-zero exit status. From [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Customizing-the-Build-Step):

> ### Customizing the Build Step
>
> [...]
>   When one of the build commands returns a non-zero exit code, the Travis CI build runs the subsequent commands as well, and accumulates the build result.
>
> In the example above, if `bundle exec rake build` returns an exit code of 1, the following command `bundle exec rake builddoc` is still run, but the build will result in a failure.

So if your `middleman build` fails, it will return a failure status, and thus your build will fail - you don't have to do anything specific for this to happen.